# Is there a way to instantly generate an array filled with a range of values in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, range

In python I could generate an array of values

Example:

```
arr = range(0,30)
```

Is there a way to instantly generate an array filled with a range of values in Swift?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

You can create an array with a range like this:

```
var values = Array(0...100)
```

This give you an array of `[0, ..., 100]`

Answer (score 28):

You can create a range and map it into an array:

```
var array = (0...30).map { $0 }
```

The `map` closure simply returns the range element, resulting in an array whose elements are all integers included in the range. Of course it's possible to generate different element and types, such as:

```
var array = (0...30).map { "Index\($0)" }
```

which generates an array of strings `Index0`, `Index1`, etc.

Answer (score 20):

You can use this to create array that contains same value
let array = Array(repeating: 5, count: 10)

Or if you want to create an array from range you can do it like this

```
let array = [Int](1...10)
```

In this case you will get an array that contains Int values from 1 to 10

Comment: In Swift 3 I get an error for this syntax. Is there something that has changed?

Comment: Swift 4 syntax:  let array = Array(repeating: 10, count: 5)

Comment: or let array = Array(repeatElement(10, count: 5)) in Swift 4.2

Answer (score 12):

create an Int array from 0 to N-1

```
var arr = [Int](0..<N)
```

create a Float array from 0 to N-1

```
var arr = (0..<N).map{ Float($0) }
```

create a float array from 0 to 2π including 2π step 0.1

```
var arr:[Float] = stride(from: 0.0, to: .pi * 2 + 0.1, by: 0.1).map{$0}
or
var arr:[Float] = Array(stride(from: 0.0, to: .pi * 2 + 0.1, by: 0.1))
```